# Is SharePoint 2019 Supports to Bind the SSL Certificate for/Enable HTTPS for SharePoint web services Port 32843?

Tags: 2016, 2019

We have found below security risk for SharePoint web services port 32843 it is not communicated with TLS  transport-level encryption (TLS) to protect all sensitive communications

Is SharePoint 2019 Supports to Bind the SSL Certificate for/Enable HTTPS for 32843?
The SharePoint web service web site is not attached to any cert for port 32843, is there any reason ? Should we attach a certificate?

If not please we required some references from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is supported:

"Ports required for communication between SharePoint servers and service applications (the default is HTTP):
HTTP binding: TCP 32843
HTTPS binding: TCP 32844"

See [Plan security hardening for SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/security-hardening)

Comment: Thanks for reply default binding can we change to HTTPS or can we remove it?

Comment: @adilahmed You can first implement the HTTPS on port TCP 32844, and when working, edit out the binding for HTTP :)

Comment: You said supported but what will be the hostname for SSL certificate to bind SharePoint WebServices

Comment: It's your choice if you need to change from default

Comment: please can you clarify about hostname to bind and can you provide any examples?

Comment: but when i ask same question here said it is not supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180604/is-sharepoint-2019-supports-to-bind-the-ssl-certif

Comment: @adilahmed It says that it's supported for SharePoint 2019, Not that it isn't supported for SharePoint 2016. I think you should do a few tests and see how it works.